# Using unwrap_or with generic types

Tags: rust

This is what I have:

```
use activation::Activation;
use activation::Sigmoid;

pub struct MainStruct<T> {
    activation: T
}

impl<T: Activation> MainStruct<T> {
    pub fn new(activation: Option<T>) -> MainStruct<T>
        where T: Activation
    {
        // default
        let activation_fn = activation.unwrap_or(Sigmoid {});

        MainStruct {
            activation: activation_fn,
        }
    }
}
```

Where `activation::Activation` is a trait and `Sigmoid` implements the `Activation` trait. What I'm trying to do is accepting this trait as input and be able to assign a default value when it's `None` but I receive this error:

```
expected type parameter, found struct `activation::Sigmoid`
```

Not sure what is the problem or maybe I need to somehow tell the compiler that Sigmoid implements type `T` (which is our trait)?

Comment: The type of `T` is chosen by the caller yet your code will only work if it's `Sigmoid`.

Comment: @Lee sure, but can I somehow tell the compiler that T should exactly be an Activation?

Comment: What do you mean by 'exactly an `Activation`'? If it's a trait then there could be any number of implementations.

Comment: @Lee I see...but is there any solutions to define a default for that `activation` input? maybe using a match and see if it's None and then set a default value?

Comment: There's a [`default` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/core/default/) so you could add an additional constraint on `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a type parameter, the *caller* decides what type it is. However, you're trying to force `T` to be `Sigmoid` when `activation` is `None`. Yet, the caller could call `MainStruct::new` with `None::<Widgetoid>`, and the signature says it should return a `MainStruct<Widgetoid>`. Indeed, `None` is not just one constant, but an infinity of constants, one for each `T`.

Instead of using an `Option` here, you should have two distinct constructors: a generic one that takes an `Activation` directly (no `Option` anymore), and a default one that takes no parameters.

```
// Generic impl, generic constructor
impl<T: Activation> MainStruct<T> {
    pub fn new(activation: T) -> MainStruct<T>
        where T: Activation
    {
        MainStruct {
            activation: activation,
        }
    }
}

// Specific impl, specific constructor
impl MainStruct<Sigmoid> {
    pub fn default() -> MainStruct<Sigmoid> {
        Self::new(Sigmoid {}) // delegate to generic constructor
    }
}
```

Instead of making `default` an inherent static method, you may want to implement the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait instead. ([`Default` is in the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/), so you don't need to import it in order to be able to call `MainStruct::default()`.)

```
impl Default for MainStruct<Sigmoid> {
    fn default() -> MainStruct<Sigmoid> {
        Self::new(Sigmoid {})
    }
}
```